# Using Media Queries for Images

Tags: css, image, media-queries, width, viewport-units

I'm using a viewport device-width in my code. It works fine on cellphones for both text and pictures. The problem is, it zooms pictures too much on big screens so I tried to use media queries like this:

```
.img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
}

@media screen only and (min-device-width:800px) {
  .img {
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Class `.img` is applied to the div containing `<img>`

With that, it works fine on big screens now, but it doesn't work on mobile anymore. The text is still fine but the image doesn't resize to the device width like before (and like in the meta viewport). I have no clue how to fix it.

If somebody has an idea,

Thanks,

Comment: Try removing `device` from your `min-device-width`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use max-width for an image. If an image is being stretched you would want to pick the largest size of the image as the max.

```
.img {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

That way the image will only stretch out so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers guys. As i expected, the problem came from me. My "img" class was applied to the div containing the img.

The problem is, by this way, the width and max-width didn't work.

I just splitted the .img class into two class. the .divimg containing the text-align appy to the , and the .img containing width properties apply to the  (not the  like before).

Now it works fine. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use id:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<style>
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
#first{
width:100%;
}

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" id="first" />
</body>
</html>
```